# How to find the file pointer position in c++?

Tags: c++

I am currently working with files in c++ and I want to read a file after a certain position. I read online that you can't open a file to read and write simultaneously. Is there a way to return the position of the file pointer at a certain moment and use it to extract the information after it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you read was wrong.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::fstream file("test.txt", std::ios::in | std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);

  std::string s;

  file >> s;

  // get current read position
  auto read_pos = file.tellg();

  // set current write position
  file.seekp(read_pos, std::ios::beg);
  static const char data[] = "aaa";

  // write some data
  file.write(data, 3);
}
```

Comment: he did put the word `simultaneously` in there, so he might be talking about literally the same time. As in, reading in one thread and writing in another. Which I guess you might be able to do with memory-mapped files, although then you not add to the file easily afaik.

Comment: @PeterT well... there's a conversation in itself... Even in separate threads, the actual write (to buffer, to hardware cache, to journaled filesystem, to the actual disk substrate) is going to be protected by some kind of mutex.

Comment: @RichardHodges it works thanks, but it overwrites just the length of the new input. is there a way to clear the contents after a certain position?

Comment: @MasterPuf you mean truncate the file, or zero out the bytes?

Comment: @RichardHodges to zero out the bytes.

Comment: @MasterPuf there are methods for this on std::fstream. You need to read the documentation: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream